# OnCompletionListener not called once media player has been reset and initialised

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

In my code, I have a start/stop button.I am trying to play an audio clip from the raw folder.  On completion of an audio clip, the start/stop button has to change from stop mode to start mode. I don't want to loop the audio. For this,I have called OnCompletionListener. However, the listener is called only once. If the media player is reset and created again, OnCompletionListener is no longer called.

```
public void playsong(View view) {
        if (mySound != null)

        {

         if (!pause) {mySound.start();
         btnStartStop.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button);
         pause = true;




            } else {


                if (mySound.isPlaying()) {


                    mySound.stop();

                    do_it();
                }

            }
        }
    }

 mySound.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override

            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mySound) {


                do_it();

            }
        });
public void do_it() {
        mySound.reset();
        mySound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.a);
        pause = false;
        btnStartStop.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button2);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code ? 
In this example oncompletionlistner is called everytime

```
btnDemo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(objPlayer!=null){
            if(objPlayer.isPlaying())
                stopPlaying(objPlayer);
        }
        objPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),R.raw.demoaudio);
        if(objPlayer.isPlaying())
            objPlayer.pause();
        else
            objPlayer.start();
        Log.d("null", "Media Player started!");
        if(objPlayer.isLooping() != true){
            Log.d("null", "Problem in Playing Audio");
        }
        objPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                objPlayer.release();
                objPlayer = null;
            };
        });

    }
});
```

Comment: My xml file contains the line android:onClick="playsong". So I don't think that I have to use setOnClickListener.